# Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(STUDENT_ID) [0, NULL, NULL]"; SQL statement:

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Getting Below error when trying to insert Student object through REST Post method

2020-10-08 18:50:08.799 ERROR 21708 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: **could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(STUDENT_ID) [0, NULL, NULL]"; SQL statement:
insert into student (class_id, student_name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested** exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.**JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(STUDENT_ID) [0, NULL, NULL]"; SQL statement:
insert into student (class_id, student_name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-200]**

Application.properties:-

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
hibernate.check_nullability=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Student.class

```
@Entity(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Student_Id")
    private int studentID;

    @Column(name = "Student_Name")
    private String studentName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", nullable = true)
    private Classs classs;

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    
    public Classs getClasss() {
        return classs;
    }

    public void setClasss(Classs studentClass) {
        this.classs = studentClass;
    }

}
```

Classs

```
@Entity(name = "CLASSS")
public class Classs {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Classs_Id")
    private int classsId;
    
    @Column(name = "Classs_Name")
    private String classsName;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Student> students;

    public int getClasssId() {
        return classsId;
    }

    public void setClasssId(int classsId) {
        this.classsId = classsId;
    }

    public String getClasssName() {
        return classsName;
    }

    public void setClasssName(String classsName) {
        this.classsName = classsName;
    }

}
```

StudentService.class

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepostry studentRepository;

    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Student> findById(Integer id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id);
    }
    
    public Student insertStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public Student updatingStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public void deleteStudentById(int id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
        
    }
}
```

ClasssService.class

```
@Service
public class ClasssService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClasssRepository classsRepository;

    public Classs insertClass(Classs classs) {
        return classsRepository.save(classs);
    }
}
```

UniversityRegController.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/university")
public class UniversityRegController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    
    @Autowired
    private ClasssService classsService;

    @GetMapping("/students")
    public List<Student> getAllStudentsList() {
        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public Optional<Student> getStudentById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return studentService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/registerStudent")
    public Student registerStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        return studentService.insertStudent(student);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/registerClass")
    public Classs registerClass(@RequestBody Classs classs) {
        return classsService.insertClass(classs);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/updateStudent")
    public Student updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        return studentService.updatingStudent(student);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public void deleteStudentById(@PathVariable int id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
    }
}
```

URI : http://localhost:8080/university/registerStudent
REST POST method:

```
{
    "Student": 
            {     "Classs":
                            {
                                "classsId":108,
                                "classsName":"8th Class"
                            },
                "studentID": 11,
                "studentName": "Jasdfngid"
            }
}
```

Comment: You have capitalised Class_id in one entity but not the other

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it. I have applied the changes. But it seems like issue is when i am doing a simple post request through postman to create a classs object entry in the Classs table and it is making null entries for that entry in the database and later if i again execute the post method  , it is giving the above exception  :  Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CLASSS(CLASSS_ID) [0, NULL]"; SQL statement:
insert into classs (classs_name, classs_id) values (?, ?) [23505-200]

Answer (score 1):

You tried to create two rows with the same STUDENT_ID that is a PRIMARY KEY (that means it can't be the same on two rows and can't be NULL)

Comment: No, i am not creating two student rows with same STUDENT_ID . I am trying to create student database entry and classs database entry through REST Post method. But getting this error:- Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(STUDENT_ID) [0, NULL, NULL]"; SQL statement: insert into student (class_id, student_name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: Are you really sure of what data you are using ? Because "Unique index or primary key violation" means what I told you. And "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(STUDENT_ID)" means that you have a primary key violation (either NULL or duplicate) and the problem is about the STUDENT_ID column.

This really just says "the value you provided for STUDENT_ID is either NULL or duplicate"

Try your query in a sandbox and you'll see if it works. If taht's the case then it's your program that have a problem

Comment: It seems like the issue is when I am doing a simple post request through postman to create a classs object entry in the Classs table and it is making null entries for that entry in the database and later if i again execute the post method  , it is giving the above exception    Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CLASSS(CLASSS_ID) [0, NULL]"; SQL statement:
insert into classs (classs_name, classs_id) values (?, ?) [23505-200]

Comment: try printing the fields' values (classs_name, classs_id) of classs before saving it to the database. What are the outputs ? You can do it in the service or controller